# use gather of a column with Group By in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table in sql that store statistics of visits, and have below columns:

`referredURL`

`searchedWord`(words that lead the user to this page)

`Hittime`

I want a report of this table with below column:
- refferedURL
- recenReferDate
- allSearchedWors

```
select ReferredURL , MAX (HitTime) as 'Recent refer date'
from statTbl
GROUP BY ReferredURL
```

I have problem for gathering allSearchedWords, how can I gather all of the searchedWord of a group and use it as a column?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: @mj-y BTW what RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server try

```
SELECT t.ReferredURL, 
       MAX (t.HitTime) 'Recent refer date',
       (
         STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SearchedWord 
                  FROM statTbl 
                 WHERE ReferredURL = t.ReferredURL 
                   FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' ) 
       ) 'Searched Words'
  FROM statTbl t
 GROUP BY t.ReferredURL;
```

*If you need all words to be present even duplicates ditch `DISTINCT` from the subquery.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46a86/6)** example for SQL Server

If it is MySql then

```
SELECT t.ReferredURL, 
       MAX(t.HitTime) 'Recent refer date',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(SearchedWord)) 'Searched Words'
  FROM statTbl t
 GROUP BY t.ReferredURL;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4315ea/1)** example for MySql

Sample data

```
| REFERREDURL |                    HITTIME | SEARCHEDWORD |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|        url1 | May, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        apple |
|        url1 | May, 22 2013 12:00:00+0000 |       banana |
|        url1 | May, 22 2013 18:00:00+0000 |         pear |
|        url1 | May, 22 2013 18:05:00+0000 |        apple |
|        url2 | May, 22 2013 23:00:00+0000 |        apple |
```

Sample output

```
| REFERREDURL |          RECENT REFER DATE |    SEARCHED WORDS |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|        url1 | May, 22 2013 18:05:00+0000 | apple,banana,pear |
|        url2 | May, 22 2013 23:00:00+0000 |             apple |
```

Comment: hey thx its so nice! I just have a miner probplem ... statTbl is joint of 2 other tables, I wrote just statTbl to simplify the code ... an d now that I use join of 2 other table it has error! I changed your sqlfiddle example, can u please chek it? and tell me what is the problem with that? thx a lot

Comment: @mj-y You're welcome. Post in comments a link to the updated sqlfiddle  .

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/670bc     my query has error and it dont save ... its the query:    SELECT t.ReferredURL, 
       MAX (t.HitTime) 'Recent refer date',
       (
         STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SearchedWord 
                  FROM statTbl 
                 WHERE ReferredURL = t.ReferredURL FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
       ), count1
  FROM ( statTbl inner join temp1 ON statTbl.id=temp1.id) t
 GROUP BY t.ReferredURL

Comment: @mj-y what do you want to do with joined result sets and how do you want them to be joined?

Comment: the informations that I use is come from 2 table... my tables have some other columns too, such as counts of hits,etc. I just wrote some of them to simplify the  code. is that possible to use your way with join of 2 table?

Comment: @mj-y Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/670bc/7). Hope it's what you want. In the future please post all relevant information in the question or post a separate follow-up question.

Comment: yes thx a lot... sorry that I didn't say thx ... I upvoted your comment instead... really thx.